# Why can't the generated new calculation graph be backward

Tags: pytorch

This is my code to generate the artificially Datasets

```
import torch
def synthetic_data( w , b , num_examples ):
    x = torch.normal( 0 , 1 , (num_examples , ))
    y = x*x*w[0] + x*w[1] + b
    y = y + torch.normal( 0 , 0.01 , y.shape )
    return x , y
```

Then the following code is the code for training

```
import torch

w = torch.tensor([2.0 , 3.0])  #real w to generate training_set
w.requires_grad = True 

x_data , y_data = synthetic_data( w , 1 , 20 ) # generate the training_set with real w 

w = torch.tensor([0.02,0.212]) #Initialize w to let the next network train him
w.requires_grad = True

b = 1

def forward(x):
    print("id(x):" , id(x) )
    return x*x*w[0] + x*w[1] + b  
 
 
def loss(x, y):
    y_pred = forward(x)
    print("id(y_pred):" , id(y_pred) )
    return (y_pred - y)**2
 
 
for epoch in range(100): 
    for x, y in zip(x_data, y_data):
        l = loss(x,y) 
        l.backward() 
        print('\tgrad:', x, y, w.grad )
        w.data = w.data - 0.01 * w.grad.data  
        w.grad.data.zero_() 
 
    print('progress:', epoch, l.item())
 
print("predict (after training)", w.data )
```

The problem happens in backward() in the second loop

```
for epoch in range(100): 
    for x, y in zip(x_data, y_data):
        l = loss(x,y) 
        l.backward() 
        print('\tgrad:', x, y, w.grad )
        w.data = w.data - 0.01 * w.grad.data  
        w.grad.data.zero_()
```

This is the error information
`RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.`

I know that when I use backward(), all nodes in the calculation graph will be released.
But!!! in every loop : l = loss(x,y) , This sentence generated a brand new calculation graph for me . Why is it wrong to use backward on this new calculation graph next?

I think l = loss(x,y) has generated a brand new computational graph for me and generated it from scratch without using any intermediate nodes. I don't know why the backward will go wrong

Comment: add retain_graph=True will work , but I don not why I need add this , because in every loop : l = loss( x , y ) generate a brand new computation graph